How would create those shapes and this blurry look?

So I absolutely love this picture but I can't really find a way to recreate it, I can guess that it was made in photoshop but I can't find the tools and the process that the creator used. If anybody has any information or tutorial I'd gladly take it !

Here's one possible method in Photoshop.

Begin with a square canvas, and fill it green.

With the Lasso Tool, draw a roughened circular shape, and fill it black. And do the same but using different colours for the inner pieces: orange, pink, yellow, etc.  Basically you want to make something like this




Do Filters > Blur > Radial Blur, choose the Zoom option, Best Quality, and set the slider to something like 64%.



Do Filters > Texture > Craquelure, but choose the "Spatter" option from the drop down.  You may have to use different settings here depending on the size of your image, but here are my settings


And here's the finished example

